# Pivot Count Query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I am trying to create a query that would show results for a civics test for seniors. I am having trouble getting the results to show like I want them to.

Here is my query:

---

```
       select sch.name,
       u.SCS_GI_CIVICS_TEST

      from students s
      left join u_students u
      on s.dcid = u.studentsdcid
      left join schools sch
      on s.schoolid = sch.school_number

     WHERE s.enroll_status = '0 '
     and s.grade_level ='12' 
     and sch.ADDRESS is not null
     and (u.scs_gi_civics_test like '%SpEd-Exempted%'
     or u.scs_gi_civics_test IS NULL
     or u.scs_gi_civics_test like '%Passed%'
     or u.scs_gi_civics_test like '%Failed%'
     or u.scs_gi_civics_test like '%Has Not Taken%');
```

---

The schools column is fine. In my civics test results, there are NULLs, which are the same as Has not Taken. I want to merge those and count them. I need a count and percentage for NULL + HAS NOT Taken, Passed, Failed, and Sped-Exempted. I know I need to do a pivot or a case to accomplish this but, I am quite lost on how to do it with the nulls involved. 
I need the following columns: 
School, SpEd-Exempted Count, SpEd-Exempted Percent, Passed Count, Passed Percent,Failed Count, and Failed Percent, and Has Not Taken Count and Has not Taken Percent (This includes Has Not Taken + Null Values)
*** The percentage of each would come from a total of all these values.

---

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below would give you the answer. In the below query the first select with the case statement would give you all students of all schools who passed/failed/not taken/SpEd-Exempted.
The upper select would count all the students(tot_students) and also count the people who passed/failed and give the result.

The count(pass)*100/count(dcid) would give the percentage of people who passed from a school.

This query is grouped by School.

```
SELECT   sch.name,
    COUNT(sped),
    (COUNT(sped)*100/COUNT(dcid)) perc_sped,
    COUNT(pass),
    (COUNT(pass)*100/COUNT(dcid)) perc_pass,
    COUNT(fail),
    COUNT(fail)*100/COUNT(dcid) perc_fail,
    COUNT(not_taken) not_taken,
    COUNT(not_taken)*100/COUNT(dcid) perc_not_taken,
    COUNT(dcid) tot_students
  FROM
    (SELECT   s.dcid,
        sch.name,
        CASE
          WHEN u.scs_gi_civics_test LIKE '%SpEd-Exempted%'
          THEN 1
          ELSE NULL
        END sped ,
        CASE
          WHEN u.scs_gi_civics_test LIKE '%Passed%'
          THEN 1
          ELSE NULL
        END pass ,
        CASE
          WHEN u.scs_gi_civics_test LIKE '%Failed%'
          THEN 1
          ELSE NULL
        END fail ,
        CASE
          WHEN u.scs_gi_civics_test LIKE '%Has Not Taken%'
          THEN 1
          ELSE NULL
        END not_taken
      FROM
      FROM students s
      LEFT JOIN u_students u
      ON s.dcid = u.studentsdcid
      LEFT JOIN schools sch
      ON s.schoolid         = sch.school_number
      WHERE s.enroll_status = '0 '
        AND s.grade_level   ='12'
        AND sch.ADDRESS    IS NOT NULL
    )
  GROUP BY sch.name
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I will give this a try!